# If there are codes for exactly matching every elements in a list to each element in a column

Tags: r

The problem is, a doctor who received payments from different companies must report where the money come from. I have a list of officially recorded companies and a list of company names that doctor reports. The goal of the code is to check if that the database's record is accurate(There is no specific sequence of the names in the column or in the list) 
But that doctor only write part of the company name, so I have to use the agrep function to obtain a list of Boolean value.

The actual list or column are much larger, and I just construct a simpler model in following codes.
I have tried to vary the max.distance parameter. I found out when max.distance is 5 or larger, I will get 4 TRUE; otherwise I will get 4 False. I am not sure if my codes have logic problems or I didn't adjust the max.distance properly.
Hoping for any suggestions

```
df <- data.frame(CompanyInDataBase = c('Pfizer Inc', 'Shire North America Group Inc', 'Roche Inc', 'Bayor Inc'), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
report = c('Shire', 'Pfizer', 'Genetech')

for(i in 1:length(report)){
  match <- agrepl(report[i], df$CompanyInDataBase, max.distance = 0.1)
}
```

I expect the output of a list of correct Boolean value, the size of this list should be the same as CompanyInDataBase's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a functional approach (edit: missed the point of the question, don't flag as answer).

```
sapply(lapply(report, function(x) agrepl(x, df$CompanyInDataBase, max.distance=0.1)), max)

[1] 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am still confused about the max.distance. I viewed its description in R document but I still didn't quite understand...

Comment: Oh, you're asking about adjusting the max.distance parameter, not the syntax. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558974/how-to-match-a-string-with-a-tolerance-of-one-character

Comment: Syntax adjustment is also useful for me! Thank you. I just wondered if my parameter is incorrect

Comment: Ehh, I noticed that the return list's length is the length of the list "report", but I probably need the return list to be exactly the same size as "CompanyInDataBase"...

Answer (score 1):

In your case `match` holds only the answer to `agrepl(report[length(report)], df$CompanyInDataBase, max.distance = 0.1)`.
You can ask for a match per `report` with `sapply` and then ask with `any` if there was a match per `CompanyInDataBase`.

```
apply(sapply(report, agrepl, df$CompanyInDataBase, .1), 1, any)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

With the example dataset you can also use `grepl` instead of `agrepl` to get the same result:

```
apply(sapply(report, grepl, df$CompanyInDataBase, .1), 1, any)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

In case you have only one ore zero observation you can use:

```
df  <- df[1,, drop = FALSE]
for(x in df$CompanyInDataBase) {tt <- c(tt, any(sapply(report, agrepl, x, .1)))}
tt
#[1] TRUE

df  <- df[0,, drop = FALSE]
tt <- TRUE[0]
for(x in df$CompanyInDataBase) {tt <- c(tt, any(sapply(report, agrepl, x, .1)))}
tt
#logical(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but using your function code generates a new error. Every column with only one row fails to generate the expected result. It returns "dim(x) must be positive"

Comment: Yes, that's easy. You could delete 'Shire North America Group Inc', 'Roche Inc', 'Bayor Inc' in df$CompanyInDataBase.  Others stay the same. just leave one company name in DataBase

Comment: When the companies in df$CompanyInDataBase are 2 or more, your code works fine; but when it is 1 or 0, this function fails

Comment: @ZiyiGao I have added a solution which should work also for 1 or zero observations

Comment: Yeah, I see that! Thank you so much